# How javascript call methods working?

Tags: javascript, hapi.js

Hi I was looking at the core codes of hapijs framework and i noticed this.

```
 Plugin.call(this, this, [], '', null);
```

I have no idea why they are passing two `this` and `[], '', null` and what it is supposed to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this file: https://github.com/hapijs/hapi/blob/master/lib/plugin.js#L21

As mentioned, the first `this` is passing context: `fun.call(thisArg[, arg1[, arg2[, ...]]])`

Given the function's arguments list `(server, connections, env, parent)`, the final arguments call would be:

```
server: this
connections: []
env: ''
parent: null
```

Also, read up on `.call()` here: http://mzl.la/18EkRLg

Answer (score 2):

`.call` and `.apply` are used to run a function with a different contextual `this` and allow you to pass arguments in different ways.

both receive the `this` context as the first argument.

call takes the remaining arguments as a comma separated list of arguments.

```
Plugin.call(this, this, [], '', null);
```

apply takes an array or array like object of arguments to pass to the called function.

```
Plugin.apply(this, [this, [], '', null]);
```

somewhere in the scope of that code will be a function called `Plugin`

There is plenty of documentation on `call` and `apply` as it can be a little difficult to get your head around, but once you know how and why it's used you will start using it everywhere.